# Share a Sale API - How to throw data to a share a sale account from my website

Tags: wordpress, api

I can't find any reference in this API, has anyone of you know / experience to use this API? I can't find any methods/ documentations on how to send data from my  `Wordpress` website to my share a sale account.

Comment: just to confirm, you are a merchant?

Comment: @Beldion merchant sir, poging merchant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to get your tracking code](https://account.shareasale.com/m-gettrackingcode.cfm)

All instructions are there on how to attach your tracking code to your wordpress site.